# Python class with static method and reference to self

Tags: python, static-methods, django-rest-framework

I have a class where I want to reference `self` from within a static method. Is there a way to do this?

```
class User(object):
    email = "username"
    password = "********"

    @staticmethod
    def all():
        return {"ex": self.password}


print(User.all())
```

Comment: What is your goal?  Are you trying to print all `User`s' attributes?

Comment: @EthanFurman This is to use as a placeholder object to pass a set of constants into an serializer in an api. So to answer your question, yes it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to do this is with a classmethod instead.  The way this works is that the first argument is the class itself, which you can access your variables using the dot operator.

For example:

```
class User(object):
    email = "username"
    password = "********"

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        return {"ex": cls.password}


print(User.all())
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod

Comment: Starting in Python 3.11, in case you want to type hint as well, the library `typing_extensions` contains `Self`, which refers to the in-scope class.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't.

The point of a `staticmethod` is that it does not need either instance (`self`) nor class (typically called `cls`) information to do its job.

If your `staticmethod` needs `self` then it isn't a `staticmethod` and you should just define it normally.