# Call subclass static methods from superclass in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want:
To define some rich static methods based on simple methods in the superclass and to implement the simple methods in every subclass. The methods are all static, so I don't want to instantiate first to use them.

Example Code:

```py
import abc
from abc import ABC


class Direction(ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def expr() -> str:
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def turn() -> str:
        # SUBCLASS does not exist, but that's what I want
        return "turn " + SUBCLASS.expr()


class Left(Direction):
    @staticmethod
    def expr() -> str:
        return "left"


class Right(Direction):
    @staticmethod
    def expr() -> str:
        return "right"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Left.turn())
    #    Want  "turn left"
    print(Right.turn())
    #    Want  "turn right"
```

Comment: Does it have to be a staticmethod, or would a classmethod work?

Comment: What the question asked is not possible, as `staticmethod` does not have any reference where it belongs to, so by extension it can't know its super or sub classes, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501105/python-class-with-static-method-and-reference-to-self).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a classmethod instead, as the class is passed in as the first argument:

```py
import abc
from abc import ABC


class Direction(ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def expr() -> str:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def turn(cls) -> str:
        return "turn " + cls.expr()


class Left(Direction):
    @staticmethod
    def expr() -> str:
        return "left"


class Right(Direction):
    @staticmethod
    def expr() -> str:
        return "right"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Left.turn())
    # "turn left"
    print(Right.turn())
    # "turn right"
```

Both staticmethods and classmethods can be called from the instance and from the class. The only disadvantage is that staticmethods can be called as a regular function, but classmethods can't (but you likely don't need this anyways).

Comment: Great answer! I code a lot in Scala / Java. With you example I think the equivalent of static in Java is actually implemented separately by `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`

Comment: Yeah, both staticmethod and classmethod work similar to Java static, but classmethod is the usual equivalent in Python—I've never seen any legitimate usecase for staticmethod that couldn't be done by a classmethod.

Comment: The nuances of the same names among different tech stacks hurt me a lot.